# Printing randomized letters between every letter in a word

Tags: python

I am making a program in Python3 that does a number of things to a file, one of the things being adding random numbers and letters between each word in the string. I want the random characters to not be on the ends of the words, for example, for the word Python:

```
P-y-t-h-o-n
```

Where the `-` are where the random characters would be.
So far I have:

```
def addCharacters(string, strength, randomLettersNumbers):
    newString = ''
    for c in string:
        letters = ''
        for k in range(strength):
            letters += random.choice(randomLettersNumbers)
        newString += c + letters
    return newString
```

Where `strength` is the amount of random characters to print between each letter, `string` is what i'm printing the letters between, and `randomLettersNumbers` is my list of random characters. However, it is printing them on the outside ends of the words too, like `-P-y-t-h-o-n-`, how would I fix it so it is only on the inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Your code and it seems that the character inserted in front of the string might be caused by a blank space. To avoid inserting the random character at the end just slice the string and add the last character in the return statement:

```
def addCharacters(string, strength, randomLettersNumbers):
    newString = ''
    for c in string[:-1]:
        letters = ''
        for k in range(strength):
            letters += random.choice(randomLettersNumbers)
        newString += c + letters
    return newString+string[-1]+' '

def processSentence(string,strength,randomLettersNumbers):
    return "".join([addCharacters(s,strength,randomLettersNumbers) for s in string.split()])
```

This code should produce the results You're looking for by splitting Your sentence. Than it applies the method individually for each word and adds a space at the end. The join() method rejoins the modified strings.

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried this for 'This is a sentence' I got: TlhliFsU wiasr Bad K zsQeYn0tvecnzcNe

Comment: i updated my code. now it should also work to process sentences.

Comment: yes! I actually have one more question.. when I try this on this: `This is a sentence, And this is a sentence.` with `This is a sentence,` on the top line and `And this is a sentence.` on the line below it, for some reason I get `Twhkiks i7s a AqnQd svehnTt5exnpc9e,o tGhiiss iis a SsleRnftYeqnscien,`, im not sure how to fix that? They are on the same line and the `And` comes before `sentence`

Comment: Firstly opening the file with `inputFile = open(originalFile, 'r')` (originalFile being user input) and then before the functions `string = inputFile.read()`

Comment: I have just realized the problem comes from another function I have that reverses the words in the file before adding the random characters. Sorry about that, I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: nice that you found the solution by yourself. keep programming. programming can only be learned by practice :)

Answer (score 1):

It is only necessary to add random letters and numbers after each letter of the original string, except the last one that only needs to be added. The code could look like this:

```
def addCharacters(string, strength, randomLettersNumbers):
    newString = ''
    n = len(string)
    for i in range(n-1):
        letters = ''
        for k in range(strength):
            letters += random.choice(randomLettersNumbers)
        newString += string[i] + letters
    newString += string[n-1]
    return newString

addCharacters("python", 2, ["X", "2"]) # 'pX2y22t22hX2oX2n'
```

Well your question is something different, what you need is to separate the word by spaces before applying "addCharacters"

```
string = "This is a sentence"
array = string.split(" ")
newArray = [addCharacters(word, 1, ["a", "b", "c"]) for word in array]
newString = " ".join(newArray)
print(newString)
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried this for 'This is a sentence' I got: `TlhliFsU wiasr Bad K
zsQeYn0tvecnzcNe`

Answer (score 0):

Focus on this line: `for c in string:`

Your code is inserting extra contents after every letter in the string, but it looks like you need to insert extra contents after every letter *except the last one.* You'll need a way to loop over all characters except the last one; there are several ways to do that (for example, using indices, or list slicing, since strings have a lot of list-like behavior in Python).

On that note, I don't think you would actually see random characters before the first letter of `string`. For debugging purposes, hardcoding the random characters instead of calling `random.choice` would help to visualize what's happening.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you! I am a beginner when it comes to this and I am unsure about how to iterate over all characters except the last, I though maybe something like `for c in range(len(string-1)):` though that is not working for me..

Comment: `for i in range(len(string) - 1): # do something with string[i] instead of c`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

def addCharacters(stringIn, strength, randomLettersNumbers):
    addedLetters=np.random.choice(randomLettersNumbers, size=(len(stringIn)-1, strength))
    return ''.join(map(''.join, zip(stringIn, map(''.join, addedLetters))))+stringIn[-1]
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> randomL=list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890")
>>> print(addCharacters("Python", 2, randomL))

P7oyumtcghbmoern
```